# Floating fill-width boxes

Tags: css, user-interface, css-float, fluid-layout

I have a `div` (or `section`, or some other block-level element) that contains child boxes.

```
<section>
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
    <div>Box 3</div>
    <div>Box 4</div>
    <div>Box 5</div>
    <div>Box 6</div>
    <div>Box 7</div>
    <div>Box 8</div>
    <div>Box 9</div>
    <div>Box 10</div>
</section>
```

Each child box has a minimum width (for example 150px) and they are all floated left. Therefore if the parent container is `[450, 600) px` wide then there would be 3 in a row, and similarly if the parent was `[600, 750) px` wide then there would be 4, etc.

```
section {
    min-width: 150px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

div {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    float: left;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DjAcV/3/).

How do I make it so that if the parent box is between a multiple of the child box width, the children fill the width of the parent. So for instance if the parent box is 660px wide, then each child would be 660px/4 or 165px wide. **I should also mention that if the parent box changes in width, the children should change accordingly.**

In my specific case, I can use media queries to do this because *luckily* the parent box is dependent on the viewport width, but I'm looking for a general solution because there are possibly other places where the parent box is truly variable. Also it becomes tedious to have to put every single case into a media query with `width` and `max-width`.

My compatibility requirements are modern browsers (IE 10+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari). I don't mind using a bit of JavaScript/jQuery but it should gracefully degrade in IE 9. IE 8 is unsupported so that isn't an issue.

I've looked into using flexbox but unfortunately Firefox only supports single-line flexbox as of now so the child flex items squish and overflow out of the flex container when I tried it.

Edit:

I started using JavaScript as per Siddhartha Gupta's answer below, however there seems to be a weird bug at some points where the row does not fill the entire space. (All rows should be filled 100% except for the last row if there aren't enough child elements.)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var sectionWidth = $('section').width(),
        childWidth = (sectionWidth / Math.floor(sectionWidth/150)) - 3;

    $('section').children().css({
        'width': childWidth + 'px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/PKsZ4/)

```
var sectionWidth = $('section').width();

//Lets calculate width of each child
//Divided parent width with the no of childs you want to show
//Then subtract 2px from it (fix for border px's)
//Again subtract 2px from it (fix for padding px's)
var childWidth = sectionWidth/8 - 2 - 2;

//Lets apply the width to each child
//Also need to remove min-width
$('section').children().css({'min-width': 0, 'width': childWidth + 'px'})
```

Comment: I tried your fiddle and the width doesn't change. I also tried wrapping the code around a `$(window).resize(function() { });` and it still doesn't work. I don't know why you are using parseInt on an integer, and can you please explain what the `4` is for?

Comment: HI, I've updated the answer as well as fiddle with comments. Just divide the parent width with the no of children you want to show in one row.

Comment: That breaks my requirement of having a `min-width`, and also I do have `box-sizing` set on the children elements. Where does `8` come from?

Comment: Well 8 is just an example no to show that with the above code you can manipulate upto 8 children. You can replace 8 with 3 also to show 3 children in a row. Also you can remove the min-width and try to resize the window of fiddle.

Comment: Does this help - http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/2f7HP/

To me it seems you missed document ready event, as with window resize you fiddle works perfectly.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if it initializes like that or not. There's something wrong with the function in the window resize, slow down when there's almost enough room for the next box to move up and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Well I have placed some logs and you can check them while resizing the window - http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/2f7HP/1/.

The issue occurs whenever the script calculates the width of child less than 150px, which is the min-width in your css.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way to do that (based on S.Gupta's answer)

```
var a;
function somefunc(){
var sectionWidth = $('section').width();  
var minChildWidth = 150; // specify min-width here  
var k = Math.floor(sectionWidth/minChildWidth);
if(k!=a){
k = 100/k;  
$('section').children().css({'width': k + '%'});
}
a=k;
}
```

I believe it is a better way, since it does not calculate and apply widths every time.That's what %-widths are made for.
if you can't achieve desired results with that, try to subtract 0.1 or 0.5% from the final k.
if you need more precise results, make a wrapper for the divs and apply borders and margins to inner containers, setting widths to the wrappers. With the proper box-sizing it should do the thing.

Those who'd rather do it without jQuery could consider the following:

**JS:**

```
var a;
function foo(){
var s = getElementById('section_id');
var minW = 150; // desired min. width for inner divs
var sWidth = s.offsetWidth;
var k = Math.floor(); 
k = (k>5)?5:k;
if(a!=k)
s.className="m"+k;
a=k;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.m1 .inner_div {width:100%}
.m2 .inner_div {width:50%}
.m3 .inner_div {width:33.3%}
.m4 .inner_div {width:25%}
.m5 .inner_div {width:20%}
...
.section {width:100%}
```

The limitations of such approach are obvious (max. number of rows in this example is 5). However, it can be applied in some cases. Imagine that you've got, say, more than 100 divs in a section, when user decides to resize the window. The answer below causes a loop though all the divs hardcoding widths of elements in pixels for several times while resizing. I bet such animation won't be smooth enough.

--
The solution without jQuery can be applied when there's a finite number of columns, which is the case when inner divs have greater min-width, e.g. if you set a min-width of 250px, and desired max-width is 500px, the number of columns is unlikely to reach 6 or more (500x5=3000px).

Comments appreciated.